# XML file does not appear to have any style information

Tags: java, xml, spring, web-services, serialization

I want to show java-objects data in JSON and XML views using Spring. I got it but with the XML view I got the following message precedingdata:
"XML file does not appear to have any style information".
I don't know how to fix/remove that message, I think that it's something related with the xml headers... But I don't know how to modify the header with spring, I am returning the object with @ResponseBody in the controller.

**Controller:**

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/funding/{uuid}.xml")
@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
public @ResponseBody PatrocinadorResource getPersistentIdentifierXML(
    @PathVariable(value = "uuid") String uuid) {
        PatrocinadorResource fResult = new PatrocinadorResource(....);
        return fResult;
}
```

**Output:** (can't post images)

```
XML file does not appear to have any style information   
<funding id="0">
      <contact/>
      <identification/>
      <name>Nombre 0</name>
      <signature>Firma 0</signature>
      <surnames>Apellido 0</surnames>
      <uuid>550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000</uuid>
</funding>
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message

> XML file does not appear to have any style information

is just a warning from the browser that it doesn't know how to display it, because the XML doesn't specify a [stylesheet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XSL). You can ignore it - **it is not actually part of your response XML**. Other applications calling your service will just see this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<funding id="0">
      <contact/>
      <identification/>
      <name>Nombre 0</name>
      <signature>Firma 0</signature>
      <surnames>Apellido 0</surnames>
      <uuid>550e8400-e29b-41d4-a716-446655440000</uuid>
</funding>
```

Note the first line (it might look a bit different) which indicates that this is an XML message. Your browser won't show it.

Comment: Thanks, I thought that my xml didn't include that first line and some spring configuration was required.